# Is there any way to view user-defined functions in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Firebug's [*DOM* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel) has the ability to display user-defined object methods by checking the *Show User-defined Functions* option.

I've been searching but can't seem to find a similar option within the Chrome DevTools. Is there a way to toggle the visibility of user-defined functions within the Chrome DevTools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome DevTools do not differenciate between the different types of variables and properties. They actually do not have an explicit panel for that.

DOM properties are generally shown unfiltered, while within the *Properties* side panel they are grouped by their prototype chain.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's a bummer. Hopefully DevTools implements something similar as I have found that feature extremely useful, especially when using a large library.

Comment: [Firebug 3 will integrate into the DevTools](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/11/10/firebug-3-next-generation-of-firebug/) and add a *DOM* panel to them. A request for re-adding the filter options there is done in [issue 154](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next/issues/154).

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll be looking forward to that release. Hopefully others find it as useful as I do.